# "Dependence" or "dependencies" of a function on multiple variables.

Tags: analysis, terminology

If we have a function $f(x)$ that depends on a single variable $x$, we can speak of the dependence of $f$ on $x$.  What is the plural of 'dependence' when it's used in this sense?  Is it a mass noun?  I.e., if $f=f(x,y,z)$, then can we speak of "the dependence of $f$ on $x$, $y$, and $z$"?  What about "the dependencies of $f$ on $x$, $y$, and $z$"?

Comment: I would go with the singular. To me, "dependencies" implies several (distinct) types of dependence, e.g. if $f$ is defined differently on several subsets or if you look asymptotically at the dependence either when $x,y,z$ go to infinity or to $0$.

Comment: @ClementC. it came up in physics paper I wrote discussing the "dependencies" of a physical quantity on experimental variables. In that context it sounds a lot more reasonable. I'm trying to decide if I should tell the editor to change it to "dependence".

Comment: I guess I really am referring to different types of functional dependence. For example, suppose $f$ varies exponentially on $x$, linearly on $y$, and logarithmically on $z$.

Comment: Mmmh... in this case, the plural looks well-suited (to me).

Comment: It seems like 'dependencies' or even 'dependences' is a reasonable choice when one wants to highlight distinct functional dependence on one variable versus another. However, 'dependence' certainly sounds more natural, and is in standard usage, while 'dependencies' does not and is not.